# How to group and sum JSON data array

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, chart.js

I have data like this

```
const
  timeStamp = 
    [ '2022-12-01', '2022-12-01'
    , '2022-12-02', '2022-12-02'
    , '2022-12-03', '2022-12-03', '2022-12-03' 
    ]
, stroke = [ '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0' ]
, tbi =    [ '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1' ]
, sci =    [ '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0' ]
```

I want to create new jsdata like this to create Chart Js

```
const jsDataFinal = 
  [ { timeStamp : '2022-12-01'
    , dxGroup   : { "stroke ": "1", "tbi ": "1", "sci ": "0" } 
    }
  , { timeStamp : '2022-12-02'
    , dxGroup   : { "stroke ": "0", "tbi ": "2", "sci ": "0" }
    }
  , { timeStamp : '2022-12-03'
    , dxGroup   : { "stroke ": "1", "tbi ": "1", "sci ": "1" } 
    } 
  ]
```

I try many time, and I want to create Chart js from my Google Sheet

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Answer (score 1):

In that case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
const timeStamp = ['2022-12-01', '2022-12-01', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-03', '2022-12-03', '2022-12-03'];
const stroke = ['1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0'];
const tbi = ['0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1'];
const sci = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0'];

const res = [...timeStamp.reduce((m, e, i) => {
  const o = m.get(e);
  const v1 = Number(stroke[i]) + (o?.dxGroup.stroke ? Number(o.dxGroup.stroke) : 0);
  const v2 = Number(tbi[i]) + (o?.dxGroup.tbi ? Number(o.dxGroup.tbi) : 0);
  const v3 = Number(sci[i]) + (o?.dxGroup.sci ? Number(o.dxGroup.sci) : 0);
  return m.set(e, { timeStamp: e, dxGroup: { stroke: v1.toString(), tbi: v2.toString(), sci: v3.toString() } });
}, new Map()).values()];
console.log(res);
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run, the following result is obtained.

```json
[
  { "timeStamp": "2022-12-01", "dxGroup": { "stroke": "1", "tbi": "1", "sci": "0" } },
  { "timeStamp": "2022-12-02", "dxGroup": { "stroke": "0", "tbi": "2", "sci": "0" } },
  { "timeStamp": "2022-12-03", "dxGroup": { "stroke": "1", "tbi": "1", "sci": "1" } }
]
```

#### Reference:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this one

```js
    const timeStamp = [  '2022-12-01', '2022-12-01', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-02', '2022-12-03', '2022-12-03', '2022-12-03'  ]

    const stroke = [ '1', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0' ]
    const tbi =    [ '0', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1' ]
    const sci =    [ '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0' ]



    //Format Data

    let result =[];

    timeStamp?.forEach((item, index) => {
      let resultObj = {timeStamp:item}
      let dxGroup = {stroke: stroke[index], tbi: tbi[index], sci:sci[index]}
      resultObj = {...resultObj, dxGroup}

      result.push(resultObj)
    })

    console.log(result)
```